# variable + value macro expansion

Tags: c++, c

I tried without any result.
My code looks like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

#define R() ( rand() )
#define H(a,b) ( a ## b )
#define S(a) ( # a )
#define CAT() H(S(distinct_name_), R())


int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout << CAT() << std::endl; 
    std::cout << CAT() << std::endl;
    std::cout << CAT() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to get a result like this:

```
distinct_name_12233
distinct_name_147
distinct_name_435

as a result of concatenating 
distinct_name_ (##) rand()
```

Right now I am getting an error:
term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments.
Is this achievable ??

EDIT:
I finally succeeded after couple of hours. The preprocessor still does strange things I cannot understand completely. Here it goes:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

class profiler 
{
public:
    void show()     
    {
        std::cout << "distinct_instance" << std::endl;      
    }
};

#define XX __LINE__
#define H(a,b) ( a ## b )
#define CAT(r) H(distinct_name_, r)
#define GET_DISTINCT() CAT(XX)
#define PROFILE() \
    profiler GET_DISTINCT() ;\
    GET_DISTINCT().show() ; \


int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    PROFILE()
    PROFILE()
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
distinct_instance
distinct_instance
```

Thanks @Kinopiko for `__LINE__` hint. :)

Comment: You can always look at the output of the C preprocessor using `cpp filename.cpp` if you need to debug it.

Comment: In addition, `S(distinct_name_)` would give you `("distinct_name_")`, and concatenating with `R()` would give you even when rand() would yield a random number `("distinct_name_")(1233)` . You don't want the `# a` step and the parentheses. The `##` operator works with raw tokens, not somehow with strings. I'm not even sure whether you wouldn't get even an error message when trying to concatenate `)` and `(`, both of which are punctuators.

Comment: I.e they *split* tokens, but `##` would try to *concatenate* them into one token, which can only result in an error.

Comment: It shouldn't produce any different output, but I'd prefer `cc -E` in case the particular compiler has its own special settings or macros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that a lot of people have already correctly answered this question, but as an alternative suggestion, if your preprocessor implements `__TIME__` or `__LINE__` you could get a result quite like what you want, with a line number or time concatenated, rather than a random number.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't do that. Macros are a compile-time thing and functions are called only at run time, so there's no way you could get a random number from `rand()` into your macro expansion.

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually getting is...

```
std::cout << distinct_name_rand() << std::endl;
```

distinct_name_rand() isn't a function, so it fails with a compile error.

Macros don't execute functions during compile time.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass run-time computed value to the macro since macro are evaluated at compile-time.
Try:

```
#define H(a,b) ( a ## b )
#define S(a) ( # a )
#define CAT(r) H(S(distinct_name_), r)

std::cout << CAT(rand()) << std::endl;
```